# onCancelled() doesn't get called by calling cancel() once onPostExecute() get called?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to dismiss dialog on onCancelled(Boolean aBoolean) of AsyncTask : 
1. It will get called if I call 'myAsyncTask.cancel(true)' if AsyncTask is running.
2. It won't get called if AsyncTask already called onPostExecute().

Do anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, AsyncTask.cancel() doesn’t kill the Thread with no regard for the consequences. All it does is set the AsyncTask to a “cancelled” state. It’s up to the developer of AsyncTask to adhere cancel state.

One of the strategies is to check isCancelled() from time to time and act appropriately. onPostExecute you can also read “cancelled” state and call onCancelled() (or any other function with common logic) manually.

Answer (score 0):

In short, You can't not.

When you called .cancel(true) methods, AsyncTask execute onCancelled instead of onPostExecute.

onPostExecute means Background Tasks is over, back to UI Thread.

I think there is new way.

In onPostExecute, just adding boolean isProcessing = true;

when you don't process onPostExecute, just switch isProcessing's value to false. (I'm not sure about that way)

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    if (isProcessing) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute - " + result); 
    }
}
```